# new method defintion is ambiguous

Tags: julia

I want to use the code from: https://github.com/nboyd/SparseInverseProblems.jl . I've not done anything with Julia before. I've tried to run the examples. The examples 
*simple_example* and *sysid* run fine. HoweverI had a problem with *smi*. First I replaced `imread` with `load` to remove the deprecation warning. Then I ran `julia run.jl` which created the following error:

```
WARNING: New definition 
    solveFiniteDimProblem(Main.GaussBlur2D, SparseInverseProblems.Loss, Array{Float64, 2}, Array{Float64, 1}, Float64) at <some path>/SparseInverseProblems.jl/examples/smi/gaussblur.jl:140
is ambiguous with: 
    solveFiniteDimProblem(SparseInverseProblems.BoxConstrainedDifferentiableModel, SparseInverseProblems.LSLoss, Array{Float64, 2}, Array{Float64, 1}, Float64) at <HOME directory>/.julia/v0.4/SparseInverseProblems/src/BoxConstrainedDifferentiableModel.jl:106.
To fix, define 
    solveFiniteDimProblem(Main.GaussBlur2D, SparseInverseProblems.LSLoss, Array{Float64, 2}, Array{Float64, 1}, Float64)
before the new definition.
Running FWA-MIERROR: LoadError: psi not implemented for model GaussBlur2D.
 in solveFiniteDimProblem at <HOME directory>/.julia/v0.4/SparseInverseProblems/src/BoxConstrainedDifferentiableModel.jl:106
while loading <some path>/SparseInverseProblems.jl/examples/smi/run.jl, in expression starting on line 76
```

Apparently the author's intention to re-implement the `solveFiniteDimProblem` in **examples/smi/gaussblur.jl** but julia doesn't go along with it. Julia first issues a warning and then uses the original implementation in **src/BoxConstrainedDifferentiableModel.jl** which leads to the error.

How can I fix that?

I'm using julia Version 0.4.5, x86_64-linux-gnu on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is quite old code from a very old julia version from only a single author. Did you try to get in touch with the author of the code directly?

Comment: @maxxilian yes, I've tried to contact the author. Even though the code is old, I image that the fix is quite simple.

Comment: I doubt very many people in the world remember the julia 0.4 syntax though

Comment: Have you tried the suggested fix?: ```define 
    solveFiniteDimProblem(Main.GaussBlur2D, SparseInverseProblems.LSLoss, Array{Float64, 2}, Array{Float64, 1}, Float64)
before the new definition.```

Comment: a little added explanation cause this is your first contact with Julia: Julia is a young language and was changing quite a lot during the 0.x phase. Now we are at 1.2 and the syntax shouldn't undergo drastic changes anymore, but it will be hard to find somebody now to bugfix 0.4 code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try if calling

```
localDescent(s :: BoxConstrainedDifferentiableModel, lossFn :: Loss, thetas ::Matrix{Float64}, w :: Vector{Float64}, y :: Vector{Float64})
```

directly does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't solve your problem but Julia 0.4 is 4 years old, and so is the SparseInverseProblems.jl package.

I'm not sure what is your use case but have you considered more up to date packages like [Optim.jl](https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/Optim.jl) and [JuliaSparse](https://github.com/JuliaSparse)?